# How do I prove that $\forall \beta\in F(\alpha)\setminus F$ is transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Let $E/F$ be a field extension.

Let $\alpha\in E$ be transcendental over $F$.

Let $\beta\in F(\alpha)\setminus F$.

Then, how do I prove that $\beta$ is transcendental over $F$?

Here's how I tried:

Since $\beta\in F(\alpha)$, there exist $f(X),g(X)\in F[X]$ such that $\beta=\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}$.

Suppos $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$.

Then, there exists $h\in F[Y]\setminus\{0\}$ such that $h(\beta)=0$. Set $n=deg(h)$.

Then, $\sum_{i=0}^n h_i (\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)})^i=0$

Hence, $(\sum_{i=0}^n h_i f^i g^{n-i})(\alpha)=0$.

To conclude, it should be proven that $\sum_{i=0}^n h_i f^i g^{n-i}$ is not a zero polynomial.

How do I prove this? Or is there another way to prove that $\beta$ is transcendental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but I think the way you are going about things might be a bit difficult. Instead, consider $F(\beta)$ as an intermediate subfield between $F$ and $F(\alpha)$. If $[F(\beta):F]$ and $[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$ are both finite, then by the multiplicativity of field extension degree, $[F(\alpha):F]$ is finite, a contradiction. Hence, if we show $[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$ is finite, it is clear that $[F(\beta):F]$ cannot be finite. See if you can show this; I am happy to post more.

Comment: Is $[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]=1$? (Since $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$ are $F$-module isomorphic, their dimensions are equal and since $F(\beta)$ is an $F$-subspace of $F(\alpha)$, they are identical. Is this argument correct?)

Comment: I don't think that's always the case necessarily. For example, consider $[\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q}(\pi^{2})]$. Try computing a polynomial over $F(\beta)$ which $\alpha$ is certainly a root of.

Comment: Right.. My mistake. Would you give me some hints for proving $[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$ is finite?

Comment: Certainly. If $\beta = f(\alpha)/g(\alpha)$, then $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are good candidates to concoct some kind of polynomial in $F(\beta)$ which $\alpha$ is a root of. I can give more hints, let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid that you may log off at the time I need more hints.. Anyway, I will try and ask for hints again. Thank you

Comment: @Rubertos: looks like egreg posted a more explicit answer. If you haven't figured it out, his answer provides the polynomial. Happy to help! :)

Comment: $[F(\beta)]:F]=n\in \mathbb{N}$ implies $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$?

Comment: @Jneven yes, field extensions of finite degree are algebraic. This can be found in any basic algebra text, but here's a quick proof of what you're asking for: consider the elements $1, \beta, \beta^{2}, \ldots, \beta^{n} \in F$. Since the dimension of $F(\beta)$ as an $F$-vector space is $n$, these elements must be $F$-linearly dependent. We conclude that $\beta$ must be a root of some nonzero $f(X) \in F[X]$.

Answer (score 5):

The relation $\beta=f(\alpha)/g(\alpha)$ can be written as
$$
f(\alpha)-\beta g(\alpha)=0
$$
which means that $\alpha$ satisfies the polynomial
$$
f(X)-\beta g(X)
$$
which has coefficients in $K(\beta)$. Since $\beta\ne0$ and $g(X)\ne0$, this polynomial is nonzero, hence $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K(\beta)$.